# Is there a way to call an existing shortcut in Premiere Pro through extend script?

Tags: adobe, extendscript

I'm busy building some automation scripts for Premiere Pro CC 2019 and would like to do a few things that appear not to have methods as described in the API documentation found here: https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/premiere-scripting-guide/latest/premiere-scripting-guide.pdf

A lot of the functionality is already doable with existing Premiere Pro shortcuts, and it would be great if I could leverage these existing shortcuts.

Is there a way to call these shortcuts from Extendscript?

I can't seem to get a handler to send shortcut keys to.

Something like:

```
app.executeShortcut({"keyCode": 22,"ctrlKey": true})
```

would be great.

Comment: also would love this. have you had any success?